# CMS using forms authentication and multiple states of login

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I am developing a new version of my content management system / shopping cart to utilise forms authentication, in conjunction with membership and role providers.

Previously I had implemented two separate authentication schemes, one for admins through an admin panel, the other for front end users of the website through a "my account" area.

The benefit of this meant that administrators could log in, but still have access to edit the un-authenticated front end areas of the website. If they needed to change content in the "my account" areas, they could then easily log in to a front end user account, and make changes to the content, while still being logged in as an admin.

The problem I am facing with forms authentication is, once logged in, I still need my admins to be able to access the logged out front end areas of the website e.g. "my account" login page.

I am sure this could be achieved in a dirty way by allowing admins to access these areas still, however I want to avoid this as it can become unmanageable.

Anyone come across a requirement like this using forms authentication / asp.net membership. I really cant see how it could work. As the software will be used to create complex websites with different content for different "my account" users, that the admins need to manage, its somewhat of a limitation of the asp.net membership / forms auth model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really follow what your problem is.  Why not just let Administrators access all screens, including not logged in screens?  You just add the Administrators group to the allow list for the page.